# What is the name of this programming rule?

Tags: law-of-demeter

There is a programming "rule" that says that a method should instead of asking for 'x' when it needs to know 'x.y.z', ask directly for 'z'. I just can't remember the name.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit, maybe with an example. I don't quite get what you are asking.

Comment: What are x and y? Classes? Objects? Methods?

Comment: Needs clarification, definitely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're after but this sounds very similar to [The Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Remember that there are always exceptions to the rule.  Some projects intentionally break this law to implement Domain Specific Languages (DSLs).  Check out JMock, for example.

Answer (score 7):

It's known as the Law of Demeter (a.k.a. Principle of Least Knowledge).
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter.

The most vivid and memorable illustration of it I've heard was *"When you're paying for a purchase in a store, the clerk doesn't ask you for your wallet so they can extract the money, they ask you for the money!"*

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of the Law of Demeter?